# Unix: Unable to use find and mdfind unable to find my targeted file

Tags: unix

So I am tring to find the path of a file using the find and mdfind command in terminal on my Macbook Pro.

The result doesn't do what I exptected. Firstly, find command isn't able to find the targeted file, while mdfind command seems to return a bunch of random files that has nothing to do what I have in mind.

[image]

Bt the way, the file definitely exist[image]

Comment: (1) [Posting images of text has downsides](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618). If you worry about non-Latin symbols possibly being displayed in a wrong way then post images as a support for text. (2) What does `~` expand to? The `#` at the end of the prompt *suggests* you're root and `~` is not `/Users/Yichen`. You told `find` to look in the wrong place. (3) I don't know `mdfind` at all but the documentation I found makes me believe it examines a lot more than filenames (the documentation is fuzzy and I really don't know if the tool matches against the name at all).

Comment: Would you expand on it? isn't ~ expand to the root directory? And my understanding of find, according to what I read, is that find would simply go over every subfiles and find me the correct path to file "how to write a letter.ppt" But it seems it doesn't do the work though

Comment: BTW, the real path to the file I am looking for is this:/Users/Yichen/Desktop/工作/BeyondWorld/教材:项目/Writing/Zhongkao-Gaokao/Task-Achievement

Comment: `~` expands to the user's home directory. It expands to the root directory if and only if the root directory is the home directory. As what user did you run `find ~ …`? What is the user's home directory? (try `echo ~`).

Comment: This is something very interesting and certainly exposed my knowledge gap. So apparently if I simply type sudo echo ～ the result is my home directory /Users/Yicen, but if I gain my root priviledge by using sudo su, some how echo ～ returns /var/root. What I still don't understand is, clearly find should be able to find  my intended file from root directory since theoretically, everything is contained in the root directory. So why can't it

Comment: It cannot because you did not run `find / …`; you run `find ~ …`. The root directory has nothing to do with the user named root. The root directory is `/` by definition. Root's (or any other user's) home directory is a concept different than the root directory, usually a different path. If you run `find ~ …` as the user whose home directory is `/Users/Yicen` then the command after tilde expansion would be `find /Users/Yicen …` and you would find the file. You run it as root (right?), apparently root's home directory is `/var/root`, so `find ~ …` was in fact `find /var/root …`.